# Libgdx - Program lags only the first time I draw a sprite

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx

When I run the program on desktop and draw any sprite, the program will frame-lag the first time that sprite is drawn, then be completely fine any subsequent times I draw the same sprite.

This happens every single time I run the program, with every sprite. I want to get rid of this annoying bug! The program still runs perfectly fine, but it makes it look unpolished.

More details: I'm using SpriteBatch and TextureRegion to draw these sprites. The frame rate is 50 FPS. I'm using the Game setup, where the main class extends Game and I use Screens to switch between scenes.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could this be due to loading the sprite from disk on first draw? Try loading all the images into memory before you start drawing anything. It will increase load times when you launch the program but it should eliminate the lag you are seeing.

Comment: I'm loading all the sprites as the program is started (the create() method), so I don't think that's the problem... Unless I'm misunderstanding how create() works.

Comment: is it 50fps constantly? If that's the case then you are doing something wrong. it should be around 60fps

Comment: Why does that make a difference? Is it something to do with vsync?